# Is checking whether string.length == 0 still faster than checking string == ""?

Tags: java, .net, string, performance

I read from a programming book about 7-8 years ago that checking `string.length == 0` is a faster way to check for empty strings. I'm wondering if that statement still holds true today (or if it has ever been true at all), because I personally think `string == ""` is more straightforward and more readable. I mostly deal with high-level languages such as .NET and java.

Comment: It depends on the implementation.

Comment: What language? - It would depend on a lot of things. Though generally strings store their length in the object and the first step of equality is to check length.

Comment: In Java, you shouldn't use == to compare Strings; it's not guaranteed to give you the right answer.

Comment: in .Net, I tend to use string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() or string.IsNullOrEmpty()

Comment: I think that `string.length == 0` would occupy less memory space, since it is primitive int comparison instead of comparing the contents of two higher level objects as strings. Although in many cases this could be optimized.

Comment: Usually, string object store their length and therefore getting and comparing the integer is very fast and has less memory access than an equals() where you - in the worst case - have to check the length and loop over the characters.
Anyway, nowadays the equals() method of a string should also check for the length first and therefore it should be - nearly - the same speed as checking for the length.

Comment: @Daniel M. That was a great answer. Could you post it again as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks.

Comment: In Java String since Java 6: `public boolean isEmpty() { return value.length == 0; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, string object store their length and therefore getting and comparing the integer is very fast and has less memory access than an equals() where you - in the worst case - have to check the length and loop over the characters.

Anyway, nowadays the equals() method of a string should also check for the length first and therefore it should be - nearly - the same speed as checking for the length.

equals part in **Java** (http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html):

```
int n = count;
if (n == anotherString.count) {...}
```

equals part in **Objective-C** (http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-476.15/CFString.c) - NSString is based on CFString:

```
if (len1 != __CFStrLength2(str2, contents2)) return false;
```

Comment: "usually" by what standard? For example, it's never done that way with native C strings (which are null terminated)

Comment: "usually" means in higher-level programming languages.
C is really low-level and yes, of course, there is no length information. Furthermore, the question was tagged with Java and he wrote he mostly deals with high-level programming languages which indicates that we talk about higher-level programming languages.

Comment: What's your evidence for this?  In .NET the recommended method would be to use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`.  You say "nowadays the equals() method *should* check length first," but you provide no evidence that this is actually the case.  Bad answer!

Comment: I'm a Java and Objective-C developer and here is the proof: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-476.15/CFString.c (`if (len1 != __CFStrLength2(str2, contents2)) return false;
`) - NSString is based on CFString; http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html (`if (n == anotherString.count) {...}`)

Answer (score 7):

The best way to do that test in Java is

```
"".equals(string)
```

because that handles the case where string is null.

As for which is faster, I think the answer is that it doesn't matter.  Both are very fast and which one is actually fastest depends on internal compiler implementation.

Comment: +1 for the [Yoda code](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html) (best practice)

Answer (score 7):

Just use `string.isEmpty()`.

(I reject `"".equals(string)` because if you have a null, that probably indicates a bug that should crash the program because it needs to be fixed.  I'm intolerant of nulls.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to be careful about using `==` to test for string equality. If the variable string is not interned, there's a good chance that the test will fail.

```
String a = "abc";
String b = a.substring(3);
System.out.println("b == \"\": " + (b == "")); // prints false
System.out.println("b.equals(\"\"): " + b.equals("")); // prints true
```

I'd use `string.length() == 0` or `string.equals("")`. Benchmark to see which is faster.

Answer (score -1):

use `"".isEmpty()` to check for an empty string.  Works great, and also returns "true" for null objects.

[String.isEmpty()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29)

.equals() throws a `NullPointerException` if it is null, which can get annoying.

Also, assuming that this is in the Java API, it is probably safe to assume that it is the fastest method.

Comment: How can it return `true` for a `null` if the `isEmpty()` is invoked on this `null` reference? I would rather expect a `NullPointerException` in this case.

Comment: because it is considered "empty"

Comment: I do not think you understood the point. In your example you invoke this method on an empty string, like this `"".isEmpty()`. Are you trying to say that this invocation: `String nullString = null; nullString.isEmpty();` will return `true`?